# ¿Cómo activar o desactivar el two way binding de un reactive forms en Angular?

Tags: angular, binding, reactiveformsmodule

Estoy realizando un ejercicio con Angular. Tengo que crear un formulario de alta de usuario y que al registrar se muestre el valor de los datos en un div en el propio HTML. En cada linia de la lista se tienen que mostrar 2 botones para modificar o eliminar el registro de usuario que corresponde. Al modificar tiene que volcar los valores de los controls en sus respectivos inputs del formulario.  He obtado por un reactive forms porque además al modificar tiene que poder hacerse de forma dinámica con data binding. Como vereis he creado un array de formGroup en el que voy haciendo push con los nuevos registros. El problema es que como el reactive forms ya tiene el two way binding cuando intento añadir un nuevo usuario se modifica el que ya habia. ¿Es posible inicializar el data binding sólo cuando se clicka el boton "modificar"?

**app.component.ts:**

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormControlName, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';


@Component
({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent
{
  title = 'formulario';


  form: FormGroup;
  
  personas: FormGroup[];
  constructor()
  {
    this.form = new FormGroup
    ({
      nombre: new FormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
      apellidos: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
      edad: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(125)]),
})
    this.personas=[];

  };

  onRegister()
{
  this.personas.push(this.form);
};

modificar(i:number)
{
  for(let x=0;x<this.personas.length;x++)
      if (i==x)
      {
       this.personas[x].controls.nombre=this.form.controls.nombre;
        this.personas[x].controls.apellidos=this.form.controls.apellidos;
        this.personas[x].controls.edad=this.form.controls.edad;
        return;
      }
    }
    
 eliminar(i:number)
{
  this.personas.splice(i,1);
};
};
```

**app.component.html:**

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <mat-card>
  <mat-card-title>Formulario</mat-card-title>
  <mat-card-content>
  <form [formGroup] = "form" class="form-group" (ngSubmit)="onRegister">
    <table cellspacing="0" >
    <tr>
    <td><mat-form-field appearance="outline"[style.width.px]=350>
      <mat-label>Nombre</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="text" #nombre formControlName="nombre" class="form-control">
      <mat-hint>Min 3 caracteres. {{nombre.value?.length || 0}}/3</mat-hint>
      <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['nombre'].errors?.required">Nombre es un campo obligatorio</mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['nombre'].errors?.minlength">Debe tener al menos 3 caracteres</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><mat-form-field appearance="outline"[style.width.px]=350>
      <mat-label>Apellidos</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="text" #apellidos formControlName="apellidos"class="form-control">
      <mat-hint>Min 3 caracteres.{{apellidos.value?.length || 0}}/3</mat-hint>
      <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['apellidos'].errors?.required">Apellidos es un campo obligatorio</mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['apellidos'].errors?.minlength">Debe tener al menos 3 caracteres</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td><mat-form-field appearance="outline"[style.width.px]=350>
      <mat-label>Edad</mat-label>
      <input matInput type= "number"  #edad formControlName="edad"class="form-control">
      <mat-hint>Entre 0 y 125 años</mat-hint>
      <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['edad'].errors?.required">Edad es un campo obligatorio</mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['edad'].errors?.min">Introduzca un valor válido entre 0 y 125</mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['edad'].errors?.max">Introduzca un valor válido entre 0 y 125</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </td>
  </tr>
   </table>
  <mat-card-actions align:end>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent"  type="submit" (click)="onRegister()" [disabled]="!form.valid">Registrar</button>
    <button mat-mini-fab color="accent"style="margin-left: 25px" type="reset"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></button>
  </mat-card-actions>
  </form>
  </mat-card-content>
  <br><br/>
  <mat-nav-list>
    <h1 matSubheader>Registro de usuarios</h1>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let persona of personas; let i=index" value="persona">
      <a matLine>{{i}} - {{this.persona.controls['nombre'].value}}
        {{this.persona.controls['apellidos'].value}}
        {{this.persona.controls['edad'].value}}
      </a>
      <mat-action-list fxLayout="row" dense>
        <button mat-raised-button  class="mat-button-modificar" (click)="modificar(i)">Modificar
          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button mat-raised-button  class="mat-button-eliminar" (click)="eliminar(i)">Eliminar
          <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <a matLine></a>
        <a matLine></a>
      </mat-action-list>
    </mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: No debes guardar todo el formulario, solo los valores con `this.form.values`

Answer (score 0):

Veo que estas empezando con Angular, al menos con su sistema de Formularios, lo odias ahora, pero después de comprenderlos los amaras.

Correcciones a realizar:

El formulario que planteas es un FormArray, ellos tienen métodos preestablecidos para funcionar, crearemos metodos nosotros para administrar este FormArray:

> Supondremos que es un FormArray dentro de un FormGroup: Es raro ver FormArrays sueltos, en un formulario real siempre van ligados,  en este ejemplo haremos una lista de estudiantes:.

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
 escuela: new FormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
 salon: new FormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
 alumnos: this.fb.array([]),
});
```

> Metodo para crear un FormGroup dentro del FormArray y/o rellenarlo cuando necesites crearlo desde data existente

```
public createFieldValue(item = null) {
const form = this.fb.group({
  nombre: new FormControl('',[Validators.required, 
  Validators.minLength(3)]),
  apellidos: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, 
  Validators.minLength(3)]),
  edad: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), 
  Validators.max(125)])
 });

  if (item) {
    form.patchValue(item);
  }

   return form;
}
```

> Metodo para agregar dentro del FormArray el FormGroup creado anteriormente:

```
public addFields(alumno: any = null) {
  const control = this.form.get('alumnos') as FormArray;
  control.push(this.createFieldValue(alumno));

}
```

> necesitamos un Getter para traer los controles (items) dentro del array, cada uno como un FormGroup

```
get itemsFields() {
  return (this.form.get('alumnos') as FormArray).controls;
}
```

> Ahora en el template renderizamos para que la magia funcione:

```
<form [formGroup] = "form" class="form-group" (ngSubmit)="onRegister">
  <table cellspacing="0" formArrayName="alumnos" *ngFor="let field of 
   itemsFields; let i=index">
    <tr [formGroupName]="i">
      <td>
         <input matInput type= "number" formControlName="edad">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input matInput formControlName="nombre">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input matInput formControlName="apellidos">
      </td>
       <button mat-raised-button color="accent"  type="submit" (click)="addField()">Registrar
       </button>
       <button mat-mini-fab color="accent"style="margin-left: 25px" type="reset"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
       </button>
    </tr>

  </table>
</form>
```

Basicameente capturas los registros con el getter y los iteras en el template, cada uno con un index unico (el index dentro del FormArray) para que no se pisen.

Answer (score 0):

Por tener  la misma referencia y así dificultar la detección de cambio lo que pretendes hacer
Mi idea es hacer una copia profunda del
FormGroup podemos hacerla mediante la librería lodash
En ruta about del enlace este ejemplo y varios mas de utilizacion de FormArray
Despliegue de la aplicacion en ruta about [ver en ruta about](https://nestdanchia.github.io/Form/)

```
 1. npm install lodash --save
    2.npm install @types/lodash --save-dev
    3.import * as _ from 'lodash';texto en itálica
```

teoría para hacerla    [[clone](https://codeutility.org/angular-deep-copy-a-reactive-form-stack-overflow)][2](https://codeutility.org/angular-deep-copy-a-reactive-form-stack-overflow)pudiendo usar los métodos que explica el vinculo o loadash elijo instalarla esta librería

Así podremos ingresar una persona en el formulario persForm esta se puede agregar al formulario que controla el arryForm al resetear a persForm la persona  se mantendrá el la lista del arryForm ya que esta tiene como referencia un clone de persForm.Tambien luego para modificar simplemente un registro se puede recorrer el arryForm y usar patchValue() hacia persForm

```
    import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import * as _ from 'lodash';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-about',
      templateUrl: './about.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
    })
    export class AboutComponent implements OnInit 
arryForm!:FormGroup;    persForm:FormGroup=this.datoBuilder.group(
        {
          nombre:['', Validators.required],
          apellidos:['', Validators.required],
          edad:['', Validators.required],
        }
      );
    constructor(private personas:FormBuilder   ){}
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.arryForm=this.personas.group({
        gente: this.personas.array([]) 
      })    
    }    
        get edad() {
        return this.persForm?.get('edad') as FormControl;
      }
      
      get apellidos() {
        return this.persForm?.get('apellidos') as FormControl;
      }
      
      get nombre() {
        return this.persForm?.get('nombre') as FormControl;
      }
      get gente():FormArray{
         return this.arryForm.get('gente')as FormArray
       }
      
       addPersona(){
       const clonedForm = _.cloneDeep(this.persForm);
       this.gente.push(clonedForm)
       }
       onPers(){
        console.log(this.persForm?.value)
      }
       clear(){
           this.persForm?.get("nombre")?.setValue("", {emitEvent:false});
           this.persForm?.get("apellidos")?.setValue("", { emitEvent: false });
            this.persForm?.get("edad")?.setValue("", { emitEvent: false });
    
       }
       deletePersona(idx: number) {
            this.gente.removeAt(idx);
        }
     onPersona(){
       console.log(this.arryForm.value)
     }
       
       }
       //html
       <section>
      <form [formGroup]="persForm" (ngSubmit)="onPers()">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label for="nombre">Nombre </mat-label>
    
          <input matInput type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" formControlName="nombre">
        </mat-form-field>
    
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label for="apellidos">Apellidos </mat-label>
    
          <input matInput type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" formControlName="apellidos">
    
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label for="edad">Edad </mat-label>
    
          <input matInput type="text" id="edad" name="edad" formControlName="edad">
    
        </mat-form-field>
        <p>
          <button mat-flat-button color="primary" type="submit">Registrar</button>
        </p>
        <p>
        <p>
          <button mat-fab color="primary" (click)="clear()">
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </p>
    
      </form>
    </section>
    
    {{this.arryForm.value | json}}
    
    <section>
      <form [formGroup]="arryForm" (ngSubmit)="onPersona()">
        <div formArrayName="gente">
          <div *ngFor="let persona of gente.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
            <mat-label>Persona : {{i + 1}}</mat-label>
            <br>
            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-label>Nombre:</mat-label>
    
              <input matInput type="text" formControlName="nombre">
            </mat-form-field>
    
    
            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-label>Apellido:</mat-label>
    
              <input matInput type="text" formControlName="apellidos">
            </mat-form-field>
    
            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-label>Edad:</mat-label>
    
              <input matInput type="text" formControlName="edad">
            </mat-form-field>
            <p>
              <button mat-flat-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="deletePersona(i)">Delete</button>
            </p>
    
          </div>
    
        </div>
    
    
    
        <p>
          <button mat-flat-button color="primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </p>
    
      </form>
      <p>
        <button mat-flat-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="addPersona()">Copiar Persona En arrayForm </button>
      </p>
    </section>
```

Para modificar desde arryForm al registro de persForm agrego un botón Modificar

```
<section>
  <form [formGroup]="arryForm" (ngSubmit)="onPersona()">
    <div formArrayName="gente">
      <div *ngFor="let persona of gente.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <mat-label>Persona : {{i + 1}}</mat-label>
        <br>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Nombre:</mat-label>

          <input matInput type="text" formControlName="nombre">
        </mat-form-field>


        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Apellido:</mat-label>

          <input matInput type="text" formControlName="apellidos">
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Edad:</mat-label>

          <input matInput type="text" formControlName="edad">
        </mat-form-field>
        <p>
          <button mat-flat-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="deletePersona(i)">Delete</button>
        </p>
        <p>
          <button mat-flat-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="update(i)">Modificar</button>
        </p>

      </div>

    </div>



    <p>
      <button mat-flat-button color="primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </p>

  </form>
  <p>
    <button mat-flat-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="addPersona()">Copiar Persona En arrayForm </button>
  </p>
</section>
```

controlo la modificacion con el metodo :

```
update(idx:number){
    let name=this.gente.at(idx).get('nombre')?.value;
    let apellidos=this.gente.at(idx).get('apellidos')?.value;
    let edad =this.gente.at(idx).get('edad')?.value;
    this.persForm?.get("nombre")?.patchValue(name);
    this.persForm?.get('apellidos')?.patchValue(apellidos);
    this.persForm?.get('edad')?.patchValue(edad);
    
    console.log('name:',name)
    
  }
```

Si queremos modificar al registro de persForm cada vez que modifiquemos al registro de arryForm asi podemos ver la deteccion del cambio a medida que modificamos el registro mediante la libreria rxjs

> Acceso a las propiedades parte del codigo ya compartido

```
get edad() {
    return this.persForm?.get('edad') as FormControl;
  }
  
  get apellidos() {
    return this.persForm?.get('apellidos') as FormControl;
  }
  
  get nombre() {
    return this.persForm?.get('nombre') as FormControl;
  }
  get gente():FormArray{
     return this.arryForm.get('gente')as FormArray
   }
```

Teoria sobre FormArray:
[[teoria](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-formarray-example-in-reactive-forms/)][3](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-formarray-example-in-reactive-forms/)

> Todo lo anterior de acuerdo a lo que entiendo que planteas ya que se
> trata de poder manejar la deteccion del cambio en Angular al usar dos
> Formularios porque hay muchas otras formas de resolverlo por ejemplo
> guardando una lista en localstorage con los valores del formulario sin
> pasar el formulario ya que al pasarlo tenemos la misma referencia y si
> desactivamos la deteccion de cambio  no sera de utilidad por ser el mismo formulario
> Forma de emitir nuevos valores desde arryForm a persForm
> con
> la libreria rxjs

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
  
  subjectEdad$:BehaviorSubject<string>=new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  subjectNombre$:BehaviorSubject<string>=new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  subjectApellido$:BehaviorSubject<string>=new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  
   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.escuchaEdad();
    -----
    -----
    //definiciones ya compartidas
   this.arryForm.controls['gente'].valueChanges.subscribe(valor=>{
  valor.map((obj: any)=>{
      this.emiteApellido(obj.apellidos);
      this.emiteNombre(obj.nombre);
      this.emiteEdad(obj.edad);
  })
  });
  }
  public emiteNombre(valor:string){
    this.persForm?.get("nombre")?.setValue(valor, { emitEvent: false });
    console.log('recibio nombre valor!!!:',valor)
    this.subjectNombre$.next(valor)
  }
  public emiteEdad(valor:string){
    this.persForm?.get("edad")?.setValue(valor, { emitEvent: false });
    console.log('recibio edad valor!!!:',valor)
    this.subjectEdad$.next(valor);
  }
   
   }
   // desde codigo obtenemos al ultimo valor del control
  public escuchaEdad(){
    this.escucha().subscribe(edad=>console.log('escucha edad :',edad))
  }
  public escucha(): Observable<string> {
        return this.subjectEdad$.asObservable();
    }
   public emiteApellido(valor:string){
    this.persForm?.get("apellidos")?.setValue(valor, { emitEvent: false });
    console.log('recibio apellidos valor!!!:',valor)
    this.subjectApellido$.next(valor)
  }
  public emiteNombre(valor:string){
    this.persForm?.get("nombre")?.setValue(valor, { emitEvent: false });
    console.log('recibio nombre valor!!!:',valor)
    this.subjectNombre$.next(valor)
  }
  public emiteEdad(valor:string){
    this.persForm?.get("edad")?.setValue(valor, { emitEvent: false });
    console.log('recibio edad valor!!!:',valor)
    this.subjectEdad$.next(valor);
  }
//en la vista podemos subscribirnos directamente mediante
<h2>Cambio Nombre:</h2>
{{subjectNombre$| async| json}}
<br>
<h2>Cambio Apellidos:</h2>
{{subjectApellido$| async| json}}
<br>
<h2>Cambio Edad:</h2>
{{subjectEdad$| async| json}}
<br>
```

Despliegue de la aplicacion en ruta about [ver en ruta about](https://nestdanchia.github.io/Form/)

> Tenes alguna dificultad adicional por la cual mi respuesta no te es de
> utilidad?

Comment: No seria mas sencillo crear un formulario con los inputs, selects, checkboxes, radiobuttons, textareas, etc, q trae html por defecto. Los personalizas con css, y creas un boton con un event listener para click, y cuando se pulse q tome y procese los valores de cada elemento del formulario segun getElementById, o usando querySelector (o como sea). Demasiada complicacion para un simple formulario.

Comment: Es de acuerdo a lo planteado en el código de la pregunta y con respecto a Angular y reactive form Un formulario  registra a cada pérsona en forma individual esta se mostrara también en otro formulario el cual guardara a esa persona y a todas a las que el formulario de registro principal de de alta .Para modificar el registro de alta se puede usar un filter con un map que vincule a los dos formularios .En la pregunta usa dos formularios al ser la misma referencia no se puede obviar el binding solo para modificar en forma directa ya que es el mismo formulario.Vos consultas por un solo formulario

Comment: Al tener dos de la forma que muestro  también se puede modificar por data binding usando setValue()